# How to use prange in jitclass

Tags: python, numba

How to use prange in function that is member of jitclass?
For example I want to parallel for in function `do_smth` using prange.

```
@jitclass([('x', float64[:])])
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.arange(10)

    def do_smth(self):
        for i in range(len(self.x)):
            pass
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a way to specify `parallel=True` in a `jitclass` member.
But you can call an external function instead. This small overhead should be minimal if parallelization is really required.

```
@nb.experimental.jitclass([('x', nb.float64[:, :])])
class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.arange(10000.).reshape((10,1000))

    def do_smth(self):
        rows, cols = self.x.shape
        sums = np.zeros(cols)
        for r in nb.prange(rows):
            print(r)
            sums[r] = np.sum(self.x[r])
        return np.sum(sums)

    def do_other(self):
        return do_other(self.x)

@nb.njit([nb.float64(nb.float64[:,:])], parallel=True)
def do_other(x):
    rows, cols = x.shape
    sums = np.zeros(cols)
    for r in nb.prange(rows):
        print(r)
        sums[r] = np.sum(x[r])
    return np.sum(sums)

t = Test()
print("Class member")
print(t.do_smth())
print("External function")
print(t.do_other())
```

Even though `prange` is used explicitly in `Test.do_smth()`, the loop is not parallelized. The order in which rows are processed is a good indication of when the loop is parallelized:

```
Class member
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
49995000.0
External function
0
2
6
3
5
9
8
7
4
1
49995000.0
```